# Error in compiling the d3 example using typescript

Tags: typescript, d3.js, looker

I'm trying to get familiar in building custom visual in Looker, so I follow one of the examples (collapsible_tree) from [Looker documentation](https://github.com/looker/custom_visualizations_v2/blob/master/src/examples/collapsible_tree/collapsible_tree.ts).

However, when I tried to compile that ts.file using tsc or yarn, I received three type errors (as shown in the image).
[image]
I tried debugging the type errors by changing the svg type to `svg?: d3.Selection<SVGSVGElement, unknown, null, undefined>` but the last two errors still persist. Would appreciate if anyone can guide me in troubleshooting this.

If this helps, I use `npm i --save-dev @types/d3` to get the d3 package, and `tsc` to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472945/d3-js-and-typescript-compilation-error), it looks like I need to explicitly spell out the element type. So I add `<BaseType>`to every Selection element, and now the compiling works.